# EFCore 5.0 Interceptor statement type

Tags: ef-core-5.0

I've implemeted an DbCommandInterceptor adding a max recursion depth to the generated SQL:

```
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("SELECT") && !command.CommandText.EndsWith($" OPTION(MAXRECURSION {MaxRecursion})"))
    { command.CommandText += $" OPTION(MAXRECURSION {MaxRecursion})"; }

    return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}
```

When not checking if the SQL starts with SELECT (`command.CommandText.StartsWith("SELECT")`) I sure get an exception on update statements (e.g. `context.SaveChanges()`). Is there a neater solution for checking the query type? Like an enum on the Command or similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Will an update statement ever result in ReaderExecutingAsync being executed?

Comment: Actually haven't tried it yet. But pretty sure, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported right now, feature request on Github created:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23719